# $watch is only working without a watchExpression

Tags: angularjs, watch

In my `$onInit` I have a `$watch`:

```
public $onInit() {
    const name = this.$state.current.name;
    console.log(name);
    this.$scope.$watch(name, (oldVal, newVal) => {
        console.log(oldVal, newVal);
        console.log(this.$state.current.name;
    });
}
```

When I run this code the `oldVal, newVal` are both `undefined` and the `this.$state.current.name` value is the same in the scope of the `$watch` and outside of it.

When I run the code without the `name` expression:

```
public $onInit() {
    const name = this.$state.current.name;
    console.log(name);
    this.$scope.$watch((oldVal, newVal) => {
        console.log(oldVal, newVal);
        console.log(this.$state.current.name);
    });
}
```

The `$watch` constantly runs. The `oldVal` is `Scope {$id: 353, .... etc` but the `newVal` is undefined. But the `this.$state.current.name` is now updated inside the `$watch` scope.

So the value of `this.$scope.current.name` does change. But when I use that as the expression in the `$watch` the `oldVal, newVal` are both undefined and the `this.$state.current.name` isn't changed inside the `$watch`.

It looks like I'm doing something wrong in the `watchExpression`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour `$watch` function.

**From docs**

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
// watchExpression - can be `expression/function` 
// listener - callback
// objectEquality - deepWatch
```

`$watch` function evaluate its `expression` wrt `$scope` on each digest cycle run. So in the first approach you're just passing `name` as `string`, so what happens is, when digest cycle kicks in, it tries to evaluate `name` variable, which obviously not exist in `$scope`, that's the reason you're getting `undefined` value for each `$watch` evaluation.

Whereas in 2nd approach you're passing `function/callback` to `$watch` function. which evaluates on each digest cycle run, which is wrong. What you supposed to do is, pass `callback` function that will return `this.$state.current.name`, then only you will get desired results in `$watch` listener function.

---

It can be solved using below

```
this.$scope.$watch(() => {
   return this.$state.current.name
}, (oldVal, newVal) => {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);
    console.log(this.$state.current.name;
});
```

Comment: Yup this works. I had no idea I had to the arrow key before the `watchExpression`. It's kinda magic to be honest. So without the arrow key the `$scope` isn't correct in the `$watch` and that's why the value would be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The watchExpression should be set as a string (even if it is already a string)
Did you try this ?

```
var name = 'some value'
this.$scope.$watch('name', (oldVal, newVal) => {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);
    console.log(this.$state.current.name);
});
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: I tried `this.$state.current.name` which is a string value. But apparently the value wasn't in the scope of the $watch. (if I understand Pankaj his answer correctly).

Comment: I edited my answer because it wasn't that clear : like it is explained in the documentation, $watch listen to an expression but that expression has to be written as a string. If you have `var name = 'some value'`, your watchExpression should be `('name', (oldVal, newVal) ...)`